# How can I compare a DataFrame with if condition?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

How can I create a new DataFrame with this if condition?

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
trips = pd.read_csv('trips.csv')
stops = pd.read_csv('stops.csv')
stop_times= pd.read_csv('stop_times.csv')

route_id = trips['route_id']
trip_id = trips['trip_id'] #deve coincidere con rip_id_stopTimes
direction_id = trips['direction_id']  # 0 -> andata, 1 -> ritorno

trip_id_stopTimes = stop_times['trip_id'] #deve coincidere con trip_id
stop_id = stop_times['stop_id'] #deve coincidere con stop_code

stop_code = stops['stop_code'] #deve coincidere con stop_id
stop_lat = stops['stop_lat']
stop_lon = stops['stop_lon']
stop_name = stops['stop_name']

#here is the problem
if str(trip_id_stopTimes) == str(trip_id) and str(stop_id) == str(stop_code):
    df['NUMEROAMAT'] = route_id
    df['IDVIAGGIO'] = trip_id
    df['ANDATA/RITORNO'] = direction_id
    df['IDVIAGGIO2'] = trip_id_stopTimes
    df['IDFERMATA'] = stop_id
    df['IDFERMATA2'] = stop_code
    df['LATITUDINEFERMATA'] = stop_lat
    df['LONGITUDINEFERMATA'] = stop_lon
    df['NOMEFERMATA'] = stop_name

df.to_csv('Amat_finale.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

I have to create a new DataFrame based on that if condition.

Comment: A bit hard to follow (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it seems likely that some variant of `df2 = df.loc[(condition1) & (condition2) & ...]` (perhaps including `.copy()`) would suffice.

Comment: Agree that some sample input and output would be very helpful. Perhaps you just need to do a merge on your dataframes and then select the data you want?

Comment: If i just execute this code, the file "Amat_finale.csv" is empty.
I'll try to explain better:

I want to compare entire columns, and create a new DataFrame only where the if is true.

Answer (score 0):

Would this get you there?  Looks like you're just testing truth values.

Can create a series of truths and use this to create your dataframe.  Now that i've read the beginning a bit more carefully it's hard to give you exactly what you want without seeing some of the data and being able to work through it myself a little.

```
truths = (trip_id_stopTimes.apply(str) == trip_id.apply(str)) & \
   (stop_id.apply(str) == stop_code.apply(str))
```

The above gives you the truth values you can then use to filter your values.  One of the things that comes to mind is that how this is setup right now, it assumes the csv files are the same lengths and ordered, etc.  You may want to consider using .merge() to take your dataframes and join them together.

Comment: Got an error : ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: The column names were wrong, they were setup as if they were variables.  Try now.

If not, you may need to ensure the objects in the comparison are both series objects.

Comment: Do the indexes on these files match?  One issue I think you're seeing here is that you're comparing specific lines to one another.  IE 500th line of trips to the 500th line of stops, etc. If you're trying to get instances where they match you may want to rethink your strategy to use a .merge function rather than testing truth values.